# Survey Package in R - svyglm with quasipoission link function for binary outcomes data, yielding relative risk?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, survey, risk, relative-risk

I'm planning to run a regression analysis to estimate [adjusted] relative risk of a binary outcome data (essentially, analyzing the relative risk or risk ratio of an event happening), using a number of independent variables with values ranging from 0-7 (discrete), with survey weight; therefore, I suppose the "survey" package is a great candidate to do that.

The package has the function svyglm which can run regression model with weights. The documentation of the package indicated a note as follows:

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/survey/html/svyglm.html

- svyglm always returns 'model-robust' standard errors; the
  Horvitz-Thompson-type standard errors used everywhere in the survey
  package are a generalisation of the model-robust 'sandwich'
  estimators. In particular, a quasi-Poisson svyglm will return correct
  standard errors for relative risk regression models.

Is this relative risk measurement applicable for binary outcomes data?